# Selecting node with JSON.NET & LINQ

Tags: json, linq, parsing

I get this JSON (I wrote it as XML):

```
<statuses>
    <metadata>
        <result_type>recent</result_type>
        <iso_language_code>tl</iso_language_code>
    </metadata>
    <created_at>Tue Jul 16 07:56:04 +0000 2013</created_at>
    <user>
        <id>1234</id>
        <id_str>4567</id_str>
        <name>Marco</name>      
    </user>
</statuses>
```

(this is how it looks):

```
{
    "statuses":[
    {
        "metadata":{
            "result_type":"recent",
            "iso_language_code":"tl"
        },
        "created_at":"Tue Jul 16 07:56:04 +0000 2013",
        "user":{
            "id":366581342,
            "id_str":"366581342",
            "name":"Marco Dalla Piazza"
        }
    }]
}
```

and I want to extract the fields `created_at` and `name` (under `user`).
How can I do it using JSON.NET library and LINQ?

Tried (for the name):

```
JObject xDoc = JObject.Parse(objectText);
var leo = xDoc.Descendants("user").Select(n => new
    name = n.Element("name").Value
{
}).First();
```

but seems that I don't have that LINQ methods (as I have in LINQ to XML).

Comment: "extrapolate"? Did you mean "extract"?

Comment: Yes! Sorry for my english :)

Comment: Please show the JSON. The XML makes no sense here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use [LINQ to JSON](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/) for this task:

```
JObject o = JObject.Parse(objectText);
var result =
    o["statuses"].Select(x => new { CreatedAt = (DateTime)x["created_at"],
                                    Name = (string)x["user"]["name"] });
```

Comment: Yep, but if the node/position change, I need to manage again my code. With "search" field on LINQ would be nice, no? Also, with your code I get a `System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.` on `created_at` field

Comment: @markzzz: Communication can't happen without a protocol. The format of the result is part of that protocol. You can't support arbitrary formats.

Comment: Even if I wrote `var createdAt = (DateTime)xDoc["statuses"]["created_at"];` it says `Accessed JArray values with invalid key value: "created_at". Array position index expected.`

Comment: @markzzz: That's because your actual JSON looks different from what I expected it to be. That's why I asked for it. Please see update.

Comment: P.S. that `(DateTime)` doesn't works well... I think I need a Parse?

Comment: @markzzz: What do you mean by "it doesn't work *well*"? Does it throw an exception?

Comment: Yes. `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.` with `Tue Jul 16 07:56:04 +0000 2013`

Comment: @markzzz: You may need to set the correct culture. Or fix your protocol. To transfer dates you should be using the ISO format: `2013-07-16T07:56:04Z`

Comment: Well, and if in some node of <user>, <name> doesnt exist? How can I check "if exist"?

Comment: @markzzz: That's really a new question. Please post it as such.